# sbt sub project testOnly ( scalatest ) not working

Tags: sbt, scalatest

I am having problem that I can not run one test using `testOnly` for a specific module..

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(Commons.settings: _*)
  .aggregate(utils, `some-service`, otherService)
```

if in sbt I do: `project some-service` and then `testOnly *MyTest`
I got an error:

```
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: testOnly
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Expected '::'
[error] Expected end of input.
```

Running all tests works fine, but not only specific one.
Anyone know how to do it ?
Thanks!

EDIT:

```
val settings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    version := appVersion,
    scalaVersion := "2.11.11",
    resolvers += Opts.resolver.mavenLocalFile,
    resolvers += "conjars" at "http://conjars.org/repo",
    resolvers += "clojars" at "https://clojars.org/repo",
    resolvers += "RedisLabs" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/",
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-unchecked",
      "-deprecation",
      "-feature",
      "-language:existentials",
      "-language:higherKinds",
      "-language:implicitConversions",
      "-language:postfixOps",
      "-Ywarn-dead-code",
      "-Ywarn-infer-any",
      "-Ywarn-unused-import",
      "-Xfatal-warnings",
      "-Xlint"
    )
  )

lazy val `some-service` = (project in file(s"$servicePrefix-service"))
  .settings(Commons.settings: _*)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= someService
  )
  .settings(
    Seq(
      daemonUser.in(Docker) := "root",
      version.in(Docker) := "latest",
      dockerBaseImage := "openjdk:8",
      dockerExposedPorts := Vector(8080),
      javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.resource=application.test.conf",
      fork in Test := true,
      startDynamoDBLocal := startDynamoDBLocal.dependsOn(compile in Test).value,
      test in Test := (test in Test).dependsOn(startDynamoDBLocal).value,
      testOnly in Test := (testOnly in Test).dependsOn(startDynamoDBLocal).value,
      testOptions in Test += dynamoDBLocalTestCleanup.value
      //dynamoDBLocalInMemory := false ,
      //dynamoDBLocalDBPath := Some("local-db/"),
      //dynamoDBLocalCleanAfterStop := true
    )
  )
  .dependsOn(utils, otherService)
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)
```

Comment: Do you have scalatest dependency in `Commons.settings` or in the `some-service`'s settings?

Comment: without it, code would not compile :)

Comment: OK, then add more of your `build.sbt` to the question, please

Comment: what do you need ?

Comment: `Commons.settings`, `some-service` project definition and if anything is floating in `build.sbt` outside of or `root` or any other project definition (i.e. `Global` or `ThisBuild` scope).

Comment: ok post edited :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found a reason.

```
testOnly in Test := (testOnly in Test).dependsOn(startDynamoDBLocal).value
```

should be changed to:

```
testOnly in Test := (testOnly in Test).dependsOn(startDynamoDBLocal).evaluated
```